# how to set column data type in db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

i wanted to change `EN_NO` length from 21 to 16 in sql table `TB_TRANSACTION`. Below are mine current sql column fields.

sql command -

```
describe table tb_transaction

column | type schema  | type name | length | scale | nulls
EN_NO|   SYSIBM    | VARCHAR   |   21  |  0   | Yes
```

i tried with this command but failed.

```
alter table tb_transaction alter column EN_NO set data type varchar(16)<br/>

Error message:
SQL0190N  ALTER TABLE "EASC.TB_TRANSACTION" specified attributes for column
"EN_NO" that are not compatible with the existing column.  SQLSTATE=42837
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the length of the longest value in that column?

Comment: currently have only 1 data in that column, `POLICY1002` 10 length

Comment: Could you do the 4 part process?  Add new column, update new from old, drop old, rename new?

Comment: Try "select cast(EN_NO as varchar(16)) from tb_transaction". What happens?

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?  It works for me on DB2 for i 7.1.  I do get a message, "Change to field EN_NO may result in data loss.".  But I can ignore that and change the table.

Answer (score 0):

We can increase the size of the column but, we can not decrease the size of column because Data lose will be happen that's why system will not allow to decrease the size.

If you still want to decrease the size, you need to drop that column and add again.